# parse XML attributes by attribute name

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to get the attributes from the following XML which is items2 in the code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ggg:Ack xmlns:ggg="http://www.ani.com" 
    ggg:errorText="Not Online" 
    ggg:errorCode="offline" 
    ggg:dateTimeSent="2018-11-27T14:46:35.5643816Z" 
    ggg:game="ANI_12345" 
    ggg:host="1"/>
```

as in the code below i am able to access game and host by elements4(0) and elements(1)

i would like to get the values of game, host  etc. by name instead of a number becuase not all of the attributes may not be returned
but everything i have tried like
elements4("game") and 
elements4("ggg:game") get an xml exception that i cant seem to find what the reason is

```
For Each item2 In elements2 'item2 = the xml above
     Dim elements4 = item2.Attributes
     host = elements4(0)
     game = elements4(1)
     Console.WriteLine(host)
     Console.WriteLine(game)
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all add this statement to the beginning of your code

```
   Imports <xmlns:ggg="http://www.ani.com">
```

then to test I did this

```
    Dim xe As XElement
    xe = <ggg:Ack xmlns:ggg="http://www.ani.com" ggg:errorText="Not Online"
             ggg:errorCode="offline"
             ggg:dateTimeSent="2018-11-27T14:46:35.5643816Z"
             ggg:game="ANI_12345"
             ggg:host="1"/>

    Dim game As String = xe.@ggg:game
```